# GIT (CLI) - Get ( only ) list of commit that differs between two branch

Tags: git

I can find many similar question but none seems to be exactly what I need:

- Get a list of all commit that are in branch A and not in branch B  ( in a way similar to how phpstorm works )
- I mean a complete list of all missing commit, every commit one line
- A cli command is what I'm looking for ( `git log master..staging` is ok but its output is multi line )

Basically I want to crosscheck by cli if something is missed on master branch in comparison to production branch and I want to do it programmatically so by script (bash).

**I'm looking for a command line, similar to `git log master..staging` but with a more concise output.**

**SOLUTION**:

- --no-pager -> no pagination in the output
- --oneline -> everything in one line
- --merges -> show only merges

`git --no-pager log --oneline --decorate --merges master..staging`

[image: phpstorm prospective]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My favourite formatting is

```
git log --oneline --decorate B..A
```

Comment: Isn't that use of `merge-base` redundant? By definition, commits that aren't in B aren't in `merge-base B anything` and commits that are in `A and B` are also in `merge-base A B`.

Comment: How true! A bit more difficult to grok than the explicit merge-base, but very true.

Comment: the output of the first one is perfect but I need it without the pagination `:`

Answer (score 3):

```
git log --oneline master..staging
```

If you're scripting and just want the commit ids, do:

```
git rev-parse master..staging
```

Comment: the output of the first one is perfect but I need it without the pagination `:`

Comment: @WonderLand: Git only enables the pager if stdout is connected to a tty. As soon as you pipe the output or run it somewhere other than a terminal the pager will not be invoked.